# Closest known position (Lat / Long) from my location in Javascript

Tags: javascript, geolocation, location

If I have 3 positions, (for ex : A,B,C) in Latitude / Longitude within my local position for A and 2 others known positions B and C.

With my position A in input how to know the closet position between B and C in output in Javascript ?

Comment: What attempts have you made to research or solve this?

Comment: calculating distance on the surface of a sphere is not trivial